# Java virtual machine version(s) that work with HAMR?

Tags: java, installation

HAMR is big data analytics engine from HAMR Analytic Technologies.

When installing HAMR for a Hadoop environment, does it work with "all" Java virtual machine versions? Or, does it only work with a particular Java version?

Thanks . . .

Answer (score 0):

HAMR requires Java version 7 or above. It has been tested and verified with JDK 1.7.